Not able to inject configmap using kustomize
Learning basics of K8 and running into something. The example for book is not working for me. I am trying to inject a configmap into my deployment using kustomize. Pasting contents of 3 file and the output of kubectl kustomize
kustomization.yaml
configMapGenerator:
  - name: outputmap
    files:
      - myconfig1.yaml
resources:
  - nginxdeployment.yaml

myconfig1.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: examplemap
data: |
  key1: value1
  key2: value2

nginxdeployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginxexercise
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      appKey: nginxValue
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        appKey: nginxValue
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: "nginx:1.21.1"
          name: mynginx
          ports:
            - name: myport
              containerPort: 80


When I run  kubectl kustomize . in the directory where the above 3 files are, should I not be seeing the configMap/env being injected into the yaml that is generated as a part of deployment? What am I doing wrong here?
apiVersion: v1
data:
  myconfig1.yaml: |
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: examplemap
    data: |
      key1: value1
      key2: value2
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: outputmap-dc4gdb5cg2
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginxexercise
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      appKey: nginxValue
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        appKey: nginxValue
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.21.1
        name: mynginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: myport


There is two things wrong with your example (although one could be intentional, which I doubt):

When you use a configMapGenerator, you don't need to pass a file which itself contains a ConfigMap. Instead, you have multiple options to either pass the contents of the ConfigMap directly or files that are injected into the ConfigMap:
configMapGenerator:
  - name: inline-key-value-pairs
    literals:
      - "key1=value1"
      - "key2=value2"

  - name: files-as-content
    files:
      - somefile.txt
      - foo.txt=somefile.txt

Considering that somefile.txt simply has the content Hello World!, you'll get the following ConfigMaps from this:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: inline-key-value-pairs
data:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: files-as-content
data:
  somefile.txt: 'Hello World!'
  foo.txt: 'Hello World!'


You never referenced the created ConfigMap in your Deployment. Kustomize has no way of knowing where you'd like to inject the ConfigMap since there can be multiple containers and you maybe would need to inject it only partially. Some examples:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app
          image: my-app:latest
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: inline-key-value-pairs
          env:
            - name: FOO
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: files-as-content
                key: foo.txt

This will leave your container my-app with three environment variables: key1, key2 and FOO, where the first two come from the inline-key-value-pairs ConfigMap and FOO is a renamed entry from files-as-content. Be aware that somefile.txt is not passed as environment variable, since it has not been referenced.



I added,
envFrom:
- configMapRef:
name: outputmap
Now the configmap is injected but the environ variables do not show up when I say env in the pod. So yes the glue you shared helps, but why is it not showing in the env output in the pod

Have you deployed the updated Deployment? You might want to use kubectl describe pods {pod-name} to see the definition of your running pod and whether it lists the injected ConfigMap. You also can view the environment variables sorted alphabetically with env | sort to ensure you haven't overlooked them.
